# How do I use Vaapi on intel hd 500 integrated graphics?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I have a media server that I use that is running Ubuntu 16 LTS. This is a headless system so access is via ssh. The media server that I am running is set up to use `vaapi` but it gives the following error when I enable it:

```
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x1ade560] No VA display found for device: /dev/dri/renderD128.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x1ade560] No VA display found for device: /dev/dri/renderD128.
```

I suspect my system might not be using the right driver because when I run `lspci` I see: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a85 (rev 0b)

I would expect if it was the right driver more specific information would be in there.

My motherboard / cpu and integrated video are as follow:
ASRock J3455B-ITX Intel Quad-Core Processor J3455 (up to 2.3 GHz) Mini ITX Motherboard/CPU Combo Integrated Intel HD Graphics 500 video card

The output of `vainfo` is as follows:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Broxton - 1.7.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Comment: I noticed that it says this is the driver for intel broxton, i think mine is apollo lake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should install two packages by
`sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver libvdpau-va-gl1`.

Comment: Thank you,I installed those 2 packages and rebooted for good measure. However I am still seeing: [AVHWDeviceContext @ 0xc50560] No VA display found for device: /dev/dri/renderD128. and lspci shows: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a85 (rev 0b) One thing i find curious is that in /dev/dri there is card0 and renderD128

Comment: Please update your post with output of `vainfo` (located in `vainfo` package).

Comment: I have very similar `vainfo` output (*Ivybridge Mobile* instead of *Broxton*). And for example VLC works well on my  Intel® HD Graphics 4000. But my system has physical display (it is laptop).

Comment: Ok, so that is not likely the cause of the problem i am having then.

Comment: You can consult your media server wiki of forum. Which media server do you use?

Comment: I am using a somewhat new version of emby ( Version 3.2.40.0 ) its a great media server being able to transcode even on this little mini itx celeron build.

Comment: I think you can read and/or post to their forums. I have searched and got two topics - [first](https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/49019-hw-transcoding-not-working/) and [second](https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/31174-hardware-encoding-on-ubuntu-server). Both topics contain your keywords (AVHWDeviceContext, renderD128, vainfo).

Comment: Following your advice i looked into the thread: https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/49019-hw-transcoding-not-working/    i think it was actually a linux permissions issue. I added emby ( the user ) to the video group and i think its working properly now.

Comment: @tdiguy It is great!