# Videos (MKV,MP4) slow

Tags: video

I have a Pentium 4 2.0 ghz with 2 GB RAM.
All videos are slow, and impossible to watch.
I'm running the latest version of lubuntu.

How can I change the codecs or install new codecs that function correctly?

In Firefox, YouTube shows the same problem, but it's better in Chromium.

Comment: what resolution are you trying to watch at? ... with those specs I cant see it going more than 720p max and that will probably give you problems .. you may be stuck at 480p ... I had an old dual core 2ghz laptop .. and I couldn't watch video at 720p without having problems with the playback .. you have a ancient computer ... back then video was very low quality .. the system cant handle the video of today like 1080p or 4K .

Comment: my resolution is 1920 x 1080, however i have dual boot and on windows 7 play normally, videos are not 4k but 1080p, the codecs is not working right.

Comment: Which video card do you have?

Comment: P5kpl-am Asus on board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a old computer, without any hardware acceleration for video playback probably - as the codecs in use today is not supported by 10-15 year old hardware. Get a new computer to play 1080p. Note that modern computers has hardware support, so even mediocre computers, like Raspberry Pi, will perform better.

There is simply no way to make modern video function in a good way on such an ancient system. It lacks hardware support (in GPU) for H264 codecs, and it does not have enough CPU power to play back in software.

It is theoretically possible to transcode it to some less demanding codec, that can be played back, but this is likely to be more hassle than to get for instance a RPi to play the video...

Answer (score 0):

I hope installing Intel VA for your Intel GMA 3100 will help - try
`sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver libvdpau-va-gl1`.
Then check VA state with `vainfo`.

You can read [this question and my answer for details](https://askubuntu.com/q/980455/66509).

You have not so bad hardware. LGA775 is great long-living socket, G31 is great chipset.
All you need is 4Gb of RAM :)